# что быстрее switch case или вызов из массива

Tags: php, массивы, производительность, switch

Вкратце: потребовалось написать отправку телеграмм-сообщения в розничные магазины при появлении нового заказа в интернет магазине.

Реализую по алгоритму:

1. Новый заказ
2. Из заказа получаю id розн. магазина
3. По id магазина получаю id телеграмма(вот тут и будет вопрос)
4. Отправляю сообщение в телеграмм по данному id

Так вот к сути вопроса. Очевидным решением является создание массива с ключами.

```
$id=[
    "store_id_1" => "telegram_id_1",
    "store_id_2" => "telegram_id_2",
    ...

];
```

И последующим получением нужного id телеграмма

```
...$id[$store_id]
```

Интересным стало быстродействие данного процесса, например в сравнении с тем же switch. Понятно, что ощутимой разницы в быстродействии для 50-100 магазинов я не замечу, однако если заполнить массив кучей значений довольно легко, писать для теста пару миллионов раз case не очень то бы хотелось. Посему задаюсь этим вопросом здесь, в надежде на помощь знающих людей

Comment: `switch` быстрее, но в вашем случае нет смысла об это задумываться.

Comment: хотя пара миллионов строк в пхп файле вряд ли скажут вам спасибо. В общем и целом, массив это структура данных которая требует накладных расходов, и в конечном счете там все равно будут сверяться значения ключей, хотя с другой стороны поиск этих ключей будет, наверное, более быстрым, чем проход по кейсам.

Comment: Еще обратите внимание на match https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.match.php если у вас PHP8. Он будет быстрее switch т.к. использует строгое сравнение

Comment: @pgood, большое спасибо за ваше совет!